# How to validate apple token from “Sign In with Apple” on the backend side (.net)?

Tags: c#, ios, .net

I'm trying to validate the token I got from the "Sign In with Apple". 
I use the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens), in POSTMAN sent the POST method with the parameters (*client_id, client_secret, grant_type,* and *refresh_token*) that I get after authorization

`{
    "access_token": "abcdefg",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "abcdefg",
    "id_token": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu"
}`

```
client_id: Apple Bundle Id; client_secret: id_token; grant_type: refresh_token; refresh_token: abcdefg
```

The response I'm getting from apple server is always: `{"error":"invalid_client"}`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you are using the id_token as the client secret. If so, this will be a stumbling point. Unfortunately, generating the client secret is complicated. E.g., take a look at https://medium.com/better-programming/apple-sign-in-custom-servers-and-an-expiry-conundrum-d1ad63223870

Comment: You are generating the client secret in a wrong way, that is the issue. If you are still interested I can write you more about this.

Comment: Not relevant anymore, thanks everyone for your help.